# Concatenar variables dentro de una función

Tags: php, funciones

Seguramente es una pregunta bastante tonta, pero tengo la duda. He encontrado por internet una función similar a esta:

```html
function saber_dia($nombredia) {
$dias = array('', 'Lunes','Martes','Miercoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sabado', 'Domingo');
$fecha = $dias[date('N', strtotime($nombredia))];
echo $fecha;
}

saber_dia('2016-10-30');
```

Y lo que no puedo es sustituir la parte de `saber_dia('2016-10-30');` por unas variables que tengo guardadas como $dia,$mes,$any. Algo así como:

```
saber_dia($any, $mes, $dia)
```

No sé si me he explicado correctamente, seguramente sea una chorrada. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes concatenar los valores con el operador ".". Por ejemplo:

```
$date= "".$any."-".$mes."-".$dia;
echo $date;
```

Luego, puedes ejecutar la función como:

```
saber_dia($date);
```

Comment: También podría usar `$date= "$any-$mes-$dia;"`.